# Understrap - sass compile error

Tags: node.js, wordpress, sass, gulp

I want to compile theme .scss file. So, according to docs I went to

```
wp-content\themes\understrap\sass\theme
```

directory. I opened `_theme.scss` file. I made changes, save and... I got bunch of errors. First and main I think is

```
{ [Error: sass\theme.scss
Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import     "theme/theme_variables"'.
       Candidates:
     theme/_theme_variables.scss
     theme/_theme_variables.css
   Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
    on line 1 of sass/theme.scss
>> @import "theme/theme_variables";  // <--------- Add your variables into     this
   ^
]
  status: 1,
  file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/under/wp-    content/themes/understrap/sass/theme.scss',
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
```

I tried to install node-sass 3.4.1 - didn't help. What I'm doing wrong? Anyone have similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the files has the same name but different extension it cant recognize witch to `import`.

Change

`@import     "theme/theme_variables"`

to

```
@import     "theme/theme_variables.scss"
```

or for both // not sure if it will work

```
@import     "theme/theme_variables.scss"
@import     "theme/theme_variables.css"
```

Comment: { [TypeError: this is not a typed array.]
  message: 'this is not a typed array.',
  name: 'TypeError',
  stack: 'TypeError: this is not a typed array.\n    at Function.from (native)\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\under\\wp-content\\themes\\understrap\\node_modules\\gulp-autoprefixer\\index.js:26:27\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)',
  __safety: undefined,
  _stack: undefined,
  plugin: 'gulp-autoprefixer',
  showProperties: true,
  showStack: true,
  fileName: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\under\\wp-content\\themes\\understrap\\sass\\theme.css' }

Comment: after change to theme_variables.scss

Comment: That mean you have some mistake is your sass.Check your files and structure.

Comment: I don't think so. It doesnt work even if I put simple
a {
    color: red;
}

Comment: I think I answered you initial question and solved the initial problem. I suggest you start over from clean understrap, build, make changes, build again. Or open a new Question regarding the new error.

Comment: Also include  ` theme_variables.scss` changes

Comment: I solve this. My I have sass compiler inside VSCode. It cause the problem. Also I update node, npm etc. Thanks